# SImple Symfony2 'Front Page' controller, router & template. Why do I still see the Welcome page?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm just starting with Symfony 2.7.3.

I've been reading "the Book", trying to piece the new-to-me concepts together.

I've put together my 1st simple example -- my 'Front Page'.

With the code below, I' expecting to see a blank page with just the words "TEST TEST" on it when I nav to

```
http://example.com/app_dev.php/
```

Instead I see the standard Symfony Welcome Page,

```
Welcome to Symfony 2.7.3

Your application is ready to start working on it at: /srv/www/test1/symfony/
What's next?

Read Symfony documentation to learn
How to create your first page in Symfony
```

I can't figure out why I'm still seeing that and not my "TEST TEST".

I'm staring at this and know I have to have missed SOMETHING simple that should be obvious :-/  But what?  Staring at it more isn't getting me anywhere.

Why don't I see the "TEST TEST", and what do I need to fix here?

```
./app/config/routing.yml
    _frontpage:
        path:      /
        defaults:  { _controller: AppBundle:FrontPage:index }


./src/AppBundle/Controller/FrontPageController.php
    <?php
    namespace AppBundle\Controller;
    use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    class FrontPageController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * @Route("/", name="index")
         */
        public function indexAction() {
            return $this->render('default/page-front.html.twig');
        }
    }

./app/Resources/views/base.html.twig
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>{% block title %}this title{% endblock %}</title>
            {% block meta %}
                <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            {% endblock %}
            {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
        </head>
        <body>
            {% block body %}{% endblock %}
            {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
        </body>
    </html>

./app/Resources/views/default/page-front.html.twig
    {% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
    {% block title %}Changed Title{% endblock %}
    {% block body %}
        <div><p>TEST TEST</p></div>
    {% endblock %}
    {% block stylesheets %}
    {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Symfony has an AppBundle included in the default installation. This bundle contains a default controlled which contains the default action for '/'. Change this controller action to handle someother path and then your controller action corresponding to 'frontpage' will be executed.

In AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController, change the indexAction as gien below

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/default", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        // replace this example code with whatever you need
        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', array(
            'base_dir' => realpath($this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..'),
        ));
    }
}
```

The same configuration was declared twice for the '/' path. The AppBundle was getting priority because of

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

line in your routing.yml file which is(most likely) declared before your route.

Comment: Changing "@Route("/",..." to "@Route("/default"," in  AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController works.  I see "TEST TEST" now.  I'm not "telling" the DefaultController.php to be used in my router.yml.  Is it really a Default then, that's hardwired into Symfony itself and will always be used?  I was *going* to delete it because I wasn't planning to use it.  Need to understand this before I do!

Comment: The same configuration was declared twice for the '/' path. The AppBundle was getting priority because of ````app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation```` line in your routing.yml file

Answer (score 0):

Since you say tht you're starting with Symfony, the suggested path is to just delete the contents of the `indexAction()` method in the `DefaultController` class of the `AppBundle` and add your own logic there.

Nothing is "hardwired" in Symfony, but `AppBundle` + `DefaultController` + route named `homepage` are usually recommended to define the homepage of your application.